# Keyboard Polling System

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events, game-loop

I'm looking for an efficient keyboard input system for a game in Java.  At present I'm using some code I found here:

[Keyboard Input Polling System](http://gpsnippets.blogspot.com/2008/03/keyboard-input-polling-system-in-java.html)

it seems a little inefficient however (please comment as to your thoughts on the code).  The full code is available here:

[Pastebin Code](http://pbin.oogly.co.uk/listings/viewlistingdetail/86f38d3f64f6064a591c1037021580)

I've only just started looking into a new solution and pulling the code apart, but does anybody have any suggestions for an efficient way of doing this in a main game loop (including an explanation)?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a KeyEventListener; when invoked, put the current key into a one-key buffer.

In the computation thread, or in a polling thread, query the current key buffer periodically.  Now, instead of that constant peeking at the I/O, you have the event listener doing it (which is already heavily optimized and cleanly implemented to use the underlying hardware) while you keep having your periodic polling.

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple keys, which are common in a game

Answer (score 0):

I think it's great code. The linked author has implemented a pull style data transfer from the keyboard instead of the usual KeyListener push method. This implementation supports [N-key rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29#n-key_rollover), however, the limit with USB is 6-8 keys simultaneously.

If you want to clean it up a bit then only store the keys that you want to pay attention to. However, this will not save you much, only a single int is written to an array each time a key is pressed.

What exactly do you find inefficient? For starters, I don't see any loops in the linked code.